Isolate() data for renderDataTable(), then edit the Table using DataTableProxy - what am I doing wrong?
I want to build a shiny application that presents a user with a selector (to subset data), a DataTable (to display the data), and an array of buttons that can be used to tag the currently selected row in the DataTable (see reprex below). Importantly, the DataTable should be isolated (i.e. it should not update and re-render when the underlying data is modified), in order to avoid resetting of filters/sorting/pages or flickering due to reloading. However, I think I am using isolate() or DataTableProxy() incorrectly (see example below). Ultimately I want to save the edited data, which is another story, but I am struggling to even get it to display correctly:
In the example below, I achieve what I intend except that the DataTable is not isolated and re-renders when I select a row and press a "Seen X times" button.
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)

test_data <- mtcars
test_data$manufacturer <- str_split_fixed(rownames(test_data), " ", 2)[,1]
test_data$model <- str_split_fixed(rownames(test_data), " ", 2)[,2]
test_data$seen <- ""

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "mtcars seen x times", titleWidth = 450),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 300, 
                   sidebarMenu(
                     id = "menu1",
                     menuItem("Cars", tabName = "Cars"),
                     selectInput("selData","Manufacturer",choices = test_data$manufacturer)
                   )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Cars",
        fluidRow(
          box(title = "details", 
              width = 12, style='overflow-y:scroll; height:80vh;',
              
              # create array of buttons
              actionButton("seen_1","Seen 1x"),
              actionButton("seen_2","Seen 2x"),
              actionButton("seen_3","Seen 3x"),
              actionButton("seen_4","Seen 4x"),
              actionButton("seen_5","Seen 5x"),
              DT::dataTableOutput("details"))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  test_data_current <- reactiveVal()
  test_data_selection <- reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(input$selData, {
    test_data_current(test_data[test_data$manufacturer == input$selData,])
    test_data_selection(test_data[test_data$manufacturer == input$selData, c("manufacturer","model","mpg","disp","hp","seen")])
  })
  
  output$details <- DT::renderDataTable({
    input$selData
    DT::datatable(test_data_selection(), 
                  rownames = F,
                  selection = "single")
  })
  
  # update data based on which button was pressed
  proxy = dataTableProxy("details")
  lapply(1:5, function(i){
    selector <- paste0("seen_",i)
    observeEvent(input[[selector]], {
      req(input$details_rows_selected)
      info <- data.frame("row" = input$details_rows_selected,
                         "col" = which(colnames(test_data_selection()) == "seen"),
                         value = recode(i, "1" = "1x", "2" = "2x", "3" = "3x", "4" = "4x", "5" = "5x"))
      edit_data <<- editData(test_data_selection(), info, proxy)
      test_data_selection(edit_data)
    })
  })
  
  
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

In the adjusted example, I call renderDataTable using data contained in isolate().
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)

test_data <- mtcars
test_data$manufacturer <- str_split_fixed(rownames(test_data), " ", 2)[,1]
test_data$model <- str_split_fixed(rownames(test_data), " ", 2)[,2]
test_data$seen <- ""

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "mtcars seen x times", titleWidth = 450),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 300, 
                   sidebarMenu(
                     id = "menu1",
                     menuItem("Cars", tabName = "Cars"),
                     selectInput("selData","Manufacturer",choices = test_data$manufacturer)
                   )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Cars",
        fluidRow(
          box(title = "details", 
              width = 12, style='overflow-y:scroll; height:80vh;',
              
              # create array of buttons
              actionButton("seen_1","Seen 1x"),
              actionButton("seen_2","Seen 2x"),
              actionButton("seen_3","Seen 3x"),
              actionButton("seen_4","Seen 4x"),
              actionButton("seen_5","Seen 5x"),
              DT::dataTableOutput("details"))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  test_data_current <- reactiveVal()
  test_data_selection <- reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(input$selData, {
    test_data_current(test_data[test_data$manufacturer == input$selData,])
    test_data_selection(test_data[test_data$manufacturer == input$selData, c("manufacturer","model","mpg","disp","hp","seen")])
  })
  
  output$details <- DT::renderDataTable({
    input$selData
    DT::datatable(isolate(test_data_selection()), 
                  rownames = F,
                  selection = "single")
  })
  
  # update data based on which button was pressed
  proxy = dataTableProxy("details")
  lapply(1:5, function(i){
    selector <- paste0("seen_",i)
    observeEvent(input[[selector]], {
      req(input$details_rows_selected)
      info <- data.frame("row" = input$details_rows_selected,
                         "col" = which(colnames(test_data_selection()) == "seen"),
                         value = recode(i, "1" = "1x", "2" = "2x", "3" = "3x", "4" = "4x", "5" = "5x"))
      edit_data <<- editData(test_data_selection(), info, proxy)
      test_data_selection(edit_data)
    })
  })
  
  
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

However, this leads to unexpected behaviour: if I press a button all the rows disappear until I change input$selData. I suspect I am using either isolate or DataTableProxy wrong, but I can't seem to figure it out. I really appreciate any help.

Answer: In this setting, calling datatable() with rownames = F causes the described unintended behaviour. The following code performs as intended:
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)

test_data <- mtcars
test_data$manufacturer <- str_split_fixed(rownames(test_data), " ", 2)[,1]
test_data$model <- str_split_fixed(rownames(test_data), " ", 2)[,2]
test_data$seen <- ""

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "mtcars seen x times", titleWidth = 450),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 300, 
                   sidebarMenu(
                     id = "menu1",
                     menuItem("Cars", tabName = "Cars"),
                     selectInput("selData","Manufacturer",choices = test_data$manufacturer)
                   )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Cars",
        fluidRow(
          box(title = "details", 
              width = 12, style='overflow-y:scroll; height:80vh;',
              
              # create array of buttons
              actionButton("seen_1","Seen 1x"),
              actionButton("seen_2","Seen 2x"),
              actionButton("seen_3","Seen 3x"),
              actionButton("seen_4","Seen 4x"),
              actionButton("seen_5","Seen 5x"),
              DT::dataTableOutput("details"))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  test_data_current <- reactiveVal()
  test_data_selection <- reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(input$selData, {
    test_data_current(test_data[test_data$manufacturer == input$selData,])
    test_data_selection(test_data[test_data$manufacturer == input$selData, c("manufacturer","model","mpg","disp","hp","seen")])
  })
  
  output$details <- DT::renderDataTable({
    input$selData
    DT::datatable(isolate(test_data_selection()),
                  selection = "single")
  })
  
  # update data based on which button was pressed
  proxy = dataTableProxy("details")
  lapply(1:5, function(i){
    selector <- paste0("seen_",i)
    observeEvent(input[[selector]], {
      req(input$details_rows_selected)
      info <- data.frame("row" = input$details_rows_selected,
                         "col" = which(colnames(test_data_selection()) == "seen"),
                         value = recode(i, "1" = "1x", "2" = "2x", "3" = "3x", "4" = "4x", "5" = "5x"))
      edit_data <<- editData(test_data_selection(), info, proxy)
      test_data_selection(edit_data)
    })
  })
  
  
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

